# JQUERY - Self-resizing navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation

So I have a navigation menu built, which resizes each li to fit the entire width of the menu with js.

```
$(function() {

    changeWidth(500);

    function changeWidth(menuWidth){
        var menuItems = $('#menu li').size();
        var itemWidth = (menuWidth/menuItems)-2;

        $('#menu').css({'width': menuWidth +'px'});
        $('#menu a').css({'width': itemWidth +'px'});
    }
});
```

Here it is set up nicely http://jsfiddle.net/MZ2wt/

I wondered if there was a way to set the width to be 100%, rather than having to declare an absolute width (currently 500px)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can set the menu width to 100% and calculate only the needed percentage per item, assuming that the container holding the menu has defined width.

Comment: Could this be appropriate for you? http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/zUpKK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MZ2wt/2/

Effectively, all it is doing is taking the `<body>` width and judging with respect to this. Bear in mind, however, that you might get some seriously odd results if your element is not a direct child of `body`. As such, if I were you, I'd pass a reference to the element you're resizing and call `$(this).parent().width()` instead of `$("body").width()`

Comment: Thanks. My menu is not a direct child of the body. I also (which I should have mentioned) would like the menu to be responsive, ie dynamically resize if the browser is narrowed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MZ2wt/16/ . Comes wrapped neatly in a jQuery plugin for your convenience!

Comment: Oh one thing, do you know how I can stop this function happening to nested lists?

Answer (score 1):

Set the menu to be 100% in CSS. Then change your function so that it measures the width of the menu, then resizes the `<li>` elements to fit within the measured width.

You can also change where it sets the width to use the `width()` method instead of the `css()` method, that way you don't have to concatenate the width into a string with `px` on the end

You could also add a resize handler that called your function when the window is resized...

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want the function to be called when the window is resized. Do you know what I would add for this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the jsFiddle, you want the LI's width to be the width of the UL equally divided by the number of LI?

I have updated your jsFiddle. Basically, I have set the LI to float left instead of display inline. Inline elements cannot have set widths. I have set the LI to have text-align center, and removed the float left from the A and put it on the LI.

http://jsfiddle.net/MZ2wt/13/

```
$(function() {
    var lis = $('#menu ul li');
    lis.css('width', ($('#menu ul').outerWidth() / lis.length) + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that
[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MZ2wt/14/)

> $(function() {
>
> ```
> changeWidth(100);// could be setted in CSS
>
> function changeWidth(menuWidth){
>     $('#menu').css({'width': menuWidth +'%'});
>     var menuWidth =  $('#menu').width();
>     var menuItems = $('#menu li').size();
>     var itemWidth = (menuWidth/menuItems)-2;
>
>    $('#menu a').css({'width': itemWidth +'px'});
> } });
> ```

Adding a listener to window resize could be interesting too.
​

Comment: Many thanks. I really want it to listen to the browser resize for responsive design.

Comment: I've just realised another problem. I have nested lists too, which this code is affecting. Is there something I can add to discount #menu li ul li ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.codropsmenu1{
    width:100%;
    padding:3px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#282828;
}
```

Add width:100% on codropsmenu1 class and dont set width for menu

```
$(function() {

    changeWidth();

    function changeWidth(){
        var menuItems = $('#menu li').size();
        var menuWidth = $('#menu').width();
        //alert(menuWidth);
        var itemWidth = (menuWidth/menuItems)-2;

        //$('#menu').css({'width': menuWidth +'px'});
        $('#menu a').css({'width': itemWidth +'px'});
    }
});
```